# javaScript как преобразовать в строку

Tags: javascript, jsf

Использую в проекте JSF + JS. JSF позволяет обращаться к бинам и брать из сервера некие значения...
грубо говоря, если я обращаюсь к бину, размещая в js текст вида #{test.value}, то плучаю некое значение.
Грубо говоря

```
var str =  #{test.value};
```

можно заменить на

```
var str = testval;
```

Но именно в таком виде, т.е. без кавычек. Соответственно получаю ошибку "Uncaught ReferenceError: testval is not defined"

Как мне окружить это значение кавычками или что то в этом роде? Что бы получать значение, возращаемое #{test.value} как стринг.

Answer (score 0):

не знаю почему, но сработало '#{test.value}'. Странно что команда не предвратилась в обычный текст, а была почему то обработана JSF

Comment: Кроме JS, подобным образом могут обрабатываться также и CSS-файлы, вот примеры: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8743850/1341148